# with Rselenium, can't navigate anymore

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium, http-verbs

I asked and answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395849/cant-execute-rsdriver-connection-refused) a few days ago and got Rselenium running fine.

now I can't navigate anymore, I don't think anything changed so I'm puzzled.

```
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com") # used to work
# Error in checkError(res) : 
#   Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

I did a bit of debugging, and `remDr$navigate` calls a method called `queryRD` where the issue happens, see the code below

```
debugging in: queryRD(qpath, "POST", qdata = list(url = url))
debug: {
    "A method to communicate with the remote server implementing the \\n          JSON wire protocol."
    getUC.params <- list(url = ipAddr, verb = method, body = qdata, 
        encode = "json")
    res <- tryCatch({
        do.call(httr::VERB, getUC.params) # VERB doesn't like the url argument its getting
    }, error = function(e) {
        e
    })
    if (inherits(res, "response")) {
        resContent <- httr::content(res, simplifyVector = FALSE)
        checkStatus(resContent)
    }
    else {
        checkError(res)
    }
}
```

`ipAddr` is a `char(0)` instead of a valid url in my case. And `VERB` doesn't like the `url` argument it's getting as a consequence.

How do I get it back running as before ?

To get the debug at the right place:

```
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome')
    remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
debugonce(remDr$navigate)
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
debugonce(queryRD)
c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the connection to the Selenium server:

```
library(RSelenium)

remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, 
                      browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com") # used to work
> remDr$getTitle()
[[1]]
[1] "Google"
...

remDr$close()
```

Answer (score 1):

For `RSelenium` users running without `Docker` and encountering the error

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Use,

```
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
```

after launching browser

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
```