# RSelenium : connection refused error

Tags: r, docker, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to connect to Selenium server using the most recent version of RSelenium. Here is the code I used:

```
install.packages('RSelenium')
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4445L
                      , browserName = "firefox"
)
remDr$open()
```

The output is as follows:

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4445: Connection refused
```

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395849/cant-execute-rsdriver-connection-refused) (using the docker). I downloaded the docker from [here](https://download.docker.com/mac/static/stable/) (as I am using macOS 10.12.5) and added the executable to PATH. After running this code:

```
system('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome')
```

I get this output:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

I have tried some other solutions but none of them worked. Can you help me please?

Comment: It's a bit easier to use the included functions to run PhantomJS than Firefox/whatever.

Comment: Give `splashr` a try — https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splashr/index.html & https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr. It's an alternative to the Selenium ecosystem based on http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Having said that, did you install Docker from https://www.docker.com/docker-mac and did you verify the Docker "hello world" example works before attempting to use Selenium?

Comment: Your docker daemon isn't running. No issue with selenium. May be docker needs sudo user privileges. Try that!

Answer (score 1):

You need administrator privileges to run a docker container, you can't do this inside an R Script unless it's run with administrator privileges. This goes for Windows or Mac users.

My recommendation is to run the command

```
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
```

inside a command-line shell you have opened with admin privileges.