# RSelenium could not navegate with Chrome

Tags: r, google-chrome, selenium

I have problems trying to implement package `RSelenium` on `R`. I already begin with the process, I downloaded selenium (*selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar*) and Google Chrome's web driver (*chromedriver.exe*). I also included in the environment variables, in path, the location of both files and a variable to the java location.

Then, I begin whit code:

```
> require(RSelenium)
> remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
> remDr$open()
```

This open the following window:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Later, when I try navegate some page I obtain the following error:

```
> remDr$navigate("http://www.la14.com")

Selenium message:unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"8112.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I don't know if it is related with browser permissions. I will grateful with your help.

Comment: have you tried to follow these steps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395849/cant-execute-rsdriver-connection-refused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your are using a chromedriver that is too old. You are using 2.9 and latest one is 2.32.

Download the latest chromedriver from below link

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.32/

And then replace the old one. This should work