# Rselenium can't connect to remote server with docker toolbox

Tags: r, docker, rselenium

I am totally new to web scraping and I am trying to do it with RSelenium. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395849/cant-execute-rsdriver-connection-refused?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to connect docker toolbox:

but still I get this error when trying to connect to remote server:

```
  > remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4445: Connection refused
```

Also, when I run this in docker toolbox terminal

```
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox
```

I get this

```
    e735076ce3ddcb183fe723dfda6dc0477bae8adf3550dc414880552e852be194
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint jolly_wing (27a6446811ba909ea9a11af7a764bdeed31aaf06e6aeea10d99fc115f779f113): Bind for 0.0.0.0:4445 failed: port is already allocated.
```

Comment: If you're already using docker anyway, [splashr](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr) is nice and requires little setup.

Comment: Maybe close your running connection using the `oracle virtualbox` and then try `docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0`. I always specify the `image` I want to run and that works fine for me (PS: you can also use the `Docker Terminal` to close it, I don't recall the command though).