# RSelenium and Docker Quick Start Terminal - cannot connect to remote server

Tags: r, docker, rselenium

I am trying to initial work of Rselenium. I followed guide from this post:
„[can't execute rsDriver (connection refused)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395849/cant-execute-rsdriver-connection-refused)”

```
library(RSelenium)
#Let's Start
shell('docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox')
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
remDr$getTitle()
```

But Consoled printed:

```
> library(RSelenium)
> #Let's Start
> shell('docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox')
Using default tag: latest
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/images/create?fromImage=selenium%2Fstandalone-firefox&tag=latest: open //./pipe/docker_engine: Nie moĹĽna odnaleĹşÄ‡ okreĹ›lonego pliku. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
Warning message:
In shell("docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox") :
  wykonywanie 'docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox' error code 1
> shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
docker: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See 'docker run --help'.
Warning message:
In shell("docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox") :
  wykonywanie 'docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox' error code: 125
> remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4445: Connection refused
> remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
> remDr$getTitle()
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

May I kindly request for a help?

Comment: I also tried to do insert directy to docker:

Answer (score 0):

Run this in cmd `@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine.exe env --shell cmd') DO @%i` and then try.

Comment: answer: token=*" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: I also tried to do insert directy to docker "docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox", but the answer... $ docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox
Using default tag: latest
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (error during conne
ct: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/info: open //./pipe/docker_e
ngine: Nie mona odnale okreonego pliku. In the default daemon configuration on W
indows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. ...

Comment: ...This error may also i
ndicate that the docker daemon is not running.). Using system default: https://i
ndex.docker.io/v1/
error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/images/cr
eate?fromImage=selenium%2Fstandalone-firefox&tag=latest: open //./pipe/docker_en
gine: Nie mona odnale okreonego pliku. In the default daemon configuration on Wi
ndows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also in
dicate that the docker daemon is not running.

Comment: Currently, i wrote command "docker-machine rm default" and "docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default" in Docker, but when I run R i got:  remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4445: Connection refused

Comment: And here is another error: > system('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
4d1819f0e77bcb763eb0103d635b7ec1b22413b7e1aec37e68fd609b01cd73bb
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint competent_euclid (132f50d2840ddd44f48cac9a79e12fcfbb1a54a251966b62a27bfbebdb5b4bb7): Bind for 0.0.0.0:4445 failed: port is already allocated.

Comment: Docker toolbox allows to run docker command only from quickstart terminal, not from a program. Can you go to quickstart terminal, and run some docker pull directly there..also to check if docker is running, go to virtualbox and see your docker machine vm, it should be in running state, just double click on it, it will take you to machine's terminal. There you can again try running docker pull and lets see of tht works..

Comment: under term "Virtualbox" Do you mean Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager or another programm?

Comment: Here is a VM outcome [link]https://imgur.com/a/jQDk8zr However Error in R or Docker remain the same: " Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint kind_williams (47645b9e1c6e232c70276d96ec1d48345baafebeb4dbb74ab360ed0d3f2d210a): Bind for 0.0.0.0:4445 failed: port is already allocated."

Comment: Your docker setup is working fine and now port is already used because of some old container I believe. Run `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)` and `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`, this will stop and remove all old containers. Try after this.

Comment: The same: > system('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
0c25ab5e44c4f4432d871a62d2775ff2a6a054e943c5f988f924f81ba5406804
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nervous_lumiere (f1417400492f5fa7df06a3c428bca8877ef7989288ded07b33d84f0c92f7a440): Bind for 0.0.0.0:4445 failed: port is already allocated.