# Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14415 after 0 ms: Connection refused

Tags: r, rselenium, netstat

After updating to RStudio Version 2022.12.0+353 (2022.12.0+353), I am unable to find a freeport using netstat.

I have never had this problem before. How do I fix this?

```
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)
remote_driver <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox',
                          verbose = F,
                          port = free_port())
Error message:
Could not open firefox browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14415 after 0 ms: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "firefox", verbose = F, netstat::free_port()) :
  Could not determine server status.
```

I have tried:

`netstat::free_port()` which failed.

I've switched the browser to chrome with no success.

Docker has never worked with my macbook.

Comment: Maybe one of the presented answers here might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395849/cant-execute-rsdriver-connection-refused/74735571#comment131986973_74735571

I had a similar problem but could not figure out what was the cause of it.

Comment: did not work :/

Comment: I had the exact same issue @bandcar and even when using a firefox browser you still need to put chromever = NULL and (for me) it worked.