# Rselenium issue with chrome

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

`Hi, I'm trying to open Rselenium with Chrome on my Windows 11 computer and laptop, but it's not working. I have already checked that Chromedriver is set to my version of Chrome (which I found on chrome://version/), and I'm using the function free_port() from the netstat library to make sure I'm connected to an available port (I have also tried changing ports manually).

I have already tried deleting the files from "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\binman" and flushing my DNS, but still no luck. This issue is happening on my laptop, computer, and a friend's laptop. However, as soon as we try it with Firefox, everything works well. If you could help, you would be a lifesaver.

I'm attaching the code and error message:

```
#=================================================================================================#
`# code`
pacman::p_load(tidyverse,
               RSelenium,
               netstat) # free port function

rs_driver_object = rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
                            chromever = "110.0.5481.30",
                            verbose = FALSE,
                            port = free_port())


remdr = rs_driver_object$client


#=================================================================================================#
`# error
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14415: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "110.0.5481.30", verbose = FALSE,  :
  Could not determine server status.``
```

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate of this question, but its answers may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45395849/5783745

Comment: Thank you for the comment. i already have something running with docker, Rselenium and chrome. The issue only happens when i try to use Rselenium and chrome by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was brought to the attention of the RSelenium developers, and it now appears to be a problem with the package. Here is the link to the entire discussion if anyone is interested: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/272.